# Populate and update a table with data from a different table

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

My site allows for a user to search for a term which returns a table of associated songs. When the "Add Track" button in a particular row is clicked after the search, the respective track name and trackId are added to the table "playlist". The problem I am having is that once "Add Track" is clicked within a different row, the data from that row is not added to the "playlist" table, but rather it just replaces the previous information. I need to be able to generate a cumulative table. Any help would be great and thanks in advance!

```
<body ng-app>

    <body ng-app>

    <div ng-controller="iTunesController">
      {{ error }}
        <form name="search" ng-submit="searchiTunes(artist)">
         <input type="search" required placeholder="Artist or Song" ng-model="artist"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
        </form>


        <div class="element"></div>
        <table id="SongInfo" ng-show="songs">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                   <th>Album Artwork</th>
                   <th>Track</th>
                   <th></th>
                   <th>Track Id</th>
                   <th>Preview</th>
                   <th>Track Info</th>
                   <th>Track Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               <tr ng-repeat="song in songs">
                    <td><img ng-src="{{song.artworkUrl60}}" 
                         alt="{{song.collectionName}}"/> 
                    </td>
                    <td>{{song.trackName}}</td>
                    <td><button ng-click="handleAdd(song)">Add Track</button></td>
                    <td>{{song.trackId}}</td>
                    <td><a href="{{song.previewUrl}}">Play</a></td>
                    <td><a href="{{song.trackViewUrl}}">View Track Info</a></td>
                    <td>{{song.trackPrice}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>


    <table id="playlist">
      <thead>
                <tr>
                   <th>Playlist</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="song in addedtracks">
            <td>{{song.trackName}}</td>
            <td>{{song.trackId}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>    
  </div>   
    </body>
```

itunes_controller.js

```
    var iTunesController = function($scope, $http){
     $scope.searchiTunes = function(artist){
             $http.jsonp('http://itunes.apple.com/search', {
                params: {
                    'callback': 'JSON_CALLBACK',
                    'term': artist,
                limit: 5,
                }
            }).then(onSearchComplete, onError)
        }
        $scope.handleAdd = function(song) {
        // this song object has all the data you need
        console.log("handle add ", song)
         $scope.addedtracks = [{song:'trackName', song:'trackID'}]
         $scope.addedtracks.push(song)
      }



    var onSearchComplete = function(response){
            $scope.data = response.data
            $scope.songs = response.data.results
        }

        var onError = function(reason){
            $scope.error = reason
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw some issues with your code. First the code below

```
$scope.addedtracks = [{song:'trackName', song:'trackID'}]
$scope.addedtracks.push(song)
```

Acording to your html, you are passing the song object to the **handleAdd**. So just remove the first line from code above. After that step, declare addedtracks array before **handleAdd** like below

```
$scope.addedtracks = [];
```

Modify the ng-repeat for the playlist like below:

```
<tr ng-repeat="song in addedtracks track by $index">
   <td>{{song.trackName}}</td>
   <td>{{song.trackId}}</td>
</tr>
```

And that's it. Note that I used **track by $index** because ngRepeat does not allow duplicate items in arrays. For more information read [Tracking and Duplicates section](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). 
Finally this is working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nhx9WHsPqfRokXyRZJkm?p=preview)